# How to move an object "Smoothly" away from another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

My game is a basic rope swinging game and I have ObjectA (The Wall) moving away from ObjectB (The Ball swinging from the rope) and then ObjectA moves back to its original position when ObjectB is no longer in the trigger. When ObjectA moves back to its orignal position, its smooth as butter, but when being pushed out of the way by ObjectB, it gets choppy, especially at highspeeds (But I need it to move at high speeds, see code below to understand). To be clear, my code is functioning completely, its just I'm looking for a sneaky trick or tip to help smooth out the "pushing away" effect, just how it is when it returns to BaseWallPosition.

```
void Update() {
         if (BallInTrigger) {
             target.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(target.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, BaseWallPosition.y), -1 * rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         else {
             target.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(target.position, BaseWallPosition, WallMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
     }

     void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col) {
         if (col.tag == "Wall") {
             BallInTrigger = true;
         }    
     }
```

There is obviously a lot more to this code, but this is the important stuff to the issue

Comment: It looks like you're reading rb.velocity in the Update method. Velocity is not updated every frame, so you'll likely see stuttering on anything dependent on its value.

Comment: I see, but the stuttering does still happen when I choose the speed to a regular float value (instead of the velocity of ObjectB), E.G var speed = 10.0f; and have the position change that way. Do you have any other ways to approach this that would be better on the stuttering?

Comment: Don't move `Rigidbody` objects in `Update` and also not by setting it's `position` rather use `MovePosition` in `FixedUpdate`